# Deflate - почему смещение выходит за пределы начала данных?

Tags: c#, huffman, deflate

Тестирую свой [`deflate`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1951) декодер. Нашел [страницу](http://evm.narod.ru/deflate.html), где автор объясняет (там есть ошибки) декодирование данным методом. Использовал для отладки своего кода.
Для дальнейших тестов воспользовался [DeflateStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.compression.deflatestream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), при помощи которой сжимаю файл, ей же разжимаю, проверяю с исходными данными, а потом исходные данные пробую разжимать своим кодом.

- 2 файла "1234567890" и "1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123" *проходят нормально*;
- третий файл "1234567890 1234567890" - *не проходит*, попробовал в ручную декодировать, выяснил, что, в закодированных данных присутствует пара <длина, смещение> смещение которой выходит за границу имеющихся декодированных данных.

---

Привожу закодированные данные в двоичной форме (байт, дв. данные (старший бит с лева)):

```
00  00110011   
01  00110100  
02  00110010  
03  00110110  
04  00110001  
05  00110101  
06  00110011  
07  10110111  
08  10110000  
09  00110100  
10  01010000  
11  00110000  
12  10000100  
13  00110011  
14  00000001
```

до первых 3-х битов байта 12 имеем данные (49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 48, 32, 49), пока все верно, ожидаем пару <9, 11>;
считываем дальше 7 битов (в обратном порядке):

```
12  10000***  
13  00110011
```

получаем 0000111 = 7, соотв. 263, т.е. *длина* = 9, доп. битов 0,
дальше нужно считать 5 битов *смещения* (в прямом порядке):

```
13  001100**
```

получаем 01100 = 12, соотв. диапазону (65-96) - **выход за границу**

Где я ошибаюсь?

**UPD**
*причем, если смещение считывать в обратном порядке, все получается; в спецификации явного указания о порядке считывания смещений не нашел (попадает под код Хаффмана, который считывается в обратном порядке), а в приведенной выше статье, автор указывает, что их нужно считывать в прямом порядке, ошибка в статье?*

Comment: Навскидку: как из 
  12  10000***  
  13  00110011
получается 0000111?



А вообще, сделайте лог <длина, смещение> при сжатии и при расжатии - должно всё стать видно

Comment: @Михаил М, начиная с 4-го бита с права считываем налево, порядок битов обратный, первый считанный бит является старшим, последний - младшим.  
Не понял  

   А вообще, сделайте лог <длина, смещение> при сжатии и при расжатии

Comment: А, действительно.



Распечатайте при сжатии, какие числа кодируются битами. Эти все длины, количество доп. битов и т.п. Т.е., допустим на неправильном числе Вы получили длина = 9, доп. битов 0, ... А записывалось что, то же?